# Python 3: Getting Value Error, sequence larger than 32

Tags: python-3.x, sequence, typeerror, valueerror, derivative

I'm trying to write a script that computes numerical derivatives using the forward, backward, and centered approximations, and plots the results. I've made a linspace from 0 to 2pi with 100 points. I've made many arrays and linspaces in the past, but I've never seen this error: "ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32"

I don't understand what the problem is. Here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.cos(x) + np.sin(x)

def f_diff(x):
    return np.cos(x) - np.sin(x)

def forward(x,h):   #forward approximation
    return (f(x+h)-f(x))/h

def backward(x,h):   #backward approximation
    return (f(x)-f(x-h))/h

def center(x,h):   #center approximation
    return (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)

x0 = 0
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
forward_result = np.zeros(x)
backward_result = np.zeros(x)
center_result = np.zeros(x)
true_result = np.zeros(x)

for i in range(x):
    forward_result[i] = forward[x0,i]
    true_result[i] = f_diff[x0]

print('Forward (x0={}) = {}'.format(x0,forward(x0,x)))
#print('Backward (x0={}) = {}'.format(x0,backward(x0,dx)))
#print('Center (x0={}) = {}'.format(x0,center(x0,dx)))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, f)
plt.plot(x,f_diff)
plt.plot(x, abs(forward_result-true_result),label='Forward difference')
```

I did try setting the linspace points to 32, but that gave me another error: "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
I don't understand that one either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue starts at `forward_result = np.zeros(x)` because x is a numpy array not a dimension. Since `x` has 100 entries, `np.zeros` wants to create object in R^x[0] times R^x[1] times R^x[3] etc. The maximum dimension is 32.

You need a flat np array.

UPDATE: On request, I add corrected lines from code above:
`forward_result = np.zeros(x.size)` creates the array of dimension 1.

Corrected evaluation of the function is done via circular brackets. Also fixed the loop:

```
for i, h in enumerate(x):
    forward_result[i] = forward(x0,h)
    true_result[i] = f_diff(x0)
```

Finally, in the figure, you want to plot numpy array vs function. Fixed version:

```
plt.plot(x, [f(val) for val in x])
plt.plot(x, [f_diff(val) for val in x])
```

Comment: Well thank you for identifying the problem, but how do I fix that? I've never heard of a flat np array.

Comment: Some explanation: A vector has dimension 1, a matrix has dimension 2. If you need to read an entry in vector, you need to provide 1 number. Reading entry in matrix requires two numbers (row and col index). You may continue the process to higher dimensions, i.e. when indexing requires more and more numbers. (the object is called tensor). You created 100-dimensional tensor (it requires 100 numbers to get a value of a single entry). But you need vector-like object.

Comment: Seriously, none of these answers have helped.

Comment: @billyyank, do you mean that the code above does not work or you don't understand why the explanation?